# Flutter: Rendering data fetched from api

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to test a simple app. The api i am using is `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/` . The data is getting rendered in the `initstate()` but when i am trying to use it in the `build()` , it gives me null error. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Here are my code snippets :

`api_service.dart`

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

```
Future postRequest() async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/');
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return json.decode(response.body);
  } else {
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
}
```

`main.dart`

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:demoapp/api_models/api_model.dart';
import 'package:demoapp/api_service/api_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  FetchAlbumRequestModel fetchAlbumRequestModel = FetchAlbumRequestModel();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> photoAlbums = [];

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    postRequest().then((albums) {
      photoAlbums = albums;
      print('PHOTOALBUMS ===> $photoAlbums');
      print(photoAlbums[0]['title']);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              photoAlbums.length.toString(),
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the response :

```
PHOTOALBUMS ===> [{userId: 1, id: 1, title: quidem molestiae enim}, {userId: 1, id: 2, title: sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa}, {userId: 1, id: 3, title: omnis laborum odio}, {userId: 1, id: 4,
title: non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio}, {userId: 1, id: 5, title: eaque aut omnis a}, {userId: 1, id: 6, title: natus impedit quibusdam illo est}, {userId: 1, id: 7, title: quibusdam
autem aliquid et et quia}, {userId: 1, id: 8, title: qui fuga est a eum}, {userId: 1, id: 9, title: saepe unde necessitatibus rem}, {userId: 1, id: 10, title: distinctio laborum qui}, {userId: 2,
id: 11, title: quam nostrum impedit mollitia quod et dolor}, {userId: 2, id: 12, title: consequatur autem doloribus natus consectetur}, {userId: 2, id: 13, title: ab rerum non rerum consequatur ut
ea unde}, {userId: 2, id: 14, title: ducimus molestias eos animi atque nihil}, {userId: 2, id: 15, title: ut pariatur rerum ipsum natus repellendus praesentium}, {userId: 2, id: 16, title:
voluptatem aut maxime inventore autem magnam atque repellat}, {userId: 2, id: 17, title: aut minima voluptatem ut velit}, {userId: 2, id: 18, title: nesciunt quia et doloremque}, {userId: 2, id:
19, title: velit pariatur quaerat similique libero omnis quia}, {userId: 2, id: 20, title: voluptas rerum iure ut enim}, {userId: 3, id: 21, title: repudiandae voluptatem optio est consequatur rem
in temporibus et}, {userId: 3, id: 22, title: et rem non provident vel ut}, {userId: 3, id: 23, title: incidunt quisquam hic adipisci sequi}, {userId: 3, id: 24, title: dolores ut et facere
placeat}, {userId: 3, id: 25, title: vero maxime id possimus sunt neque et consequatur}, {userId: 3, id: 26, title: quibusdam saepe ipsa vel harum}, {userId: 3, id: 27, title: id non nostrum
expedita}, {userId: 3, id: 28, title: omnis neque exercitationem sed dolor atque maxime aut cum}, {userId: 3, id: 29, title: inventore ut quasi magnam itaque est fugit}, {userId: 3, id: 30, title:
tempora assumenda et similique odit distinctio error}, {userId: 4, id: 31, title: adipisci laborum fuga laboriosam}, {userId: 4, id: 32, title: reiciendis dolores a ut qui debitis non quo labore},
{userId: 4, id: 33, title: iste eos nostrum}, {userId: 4, id: 34, title: cumque voluptatibus rerum architecto blanditiis}, {userId: 4, id: 35, title: et impedit nisi quae magni necessitatibus sed
aut pariatur}, {userId: 4, id: 36, title: nihil cupiditate voluptate neque}, {userId: 4, id: 37, title: est placeat dicta ut nisi rerum iste}, {userId: 4, id: 38, title: unde a sequi id}, {userId:
4, id: 39, title: ratione porro illum labore eum aperiam sed}, {userId: 4, id: 40, title: voluptas neque et sint aut quo odit}, {userId: 5, id: 41, title: ea voluptates maiores eos accusantium
officiis tempore mollitia consequatur}, {userId: 5, id: 42, title: tenetur explicabo ea}, {userId: 5, id: 43, title: aperiam doloremque nihil}, {userId: 5, id: 44, title: sapiente cum numquam
officia consequatur vel natus quos suscipit}, {userId: 5, id: 45, title: tenetur quos ea unde est enim corrupti qui}, {userId: 5, id: 46, title: molestiae voluptate non}, {userId: 5, id: 47,
title: temporibus molestiae aut}, {userId: 5, id: 48, title: modi consequatur culpa aut quam soluta alias perspiciatis laudantium}, {userId: 5, id: 49, title: ut aut vero repudiandae voluptas
ullam voluptas at consequatur}, {userId: 5, id: 50, title: sed qui sed quas sit ducimus dolor}, {userId: 6, id: 51, title: odit laboriosam sint quia cupiditate animi quis}, {userId: 6, id: 52,
title: necessitatibus quas et sunt at voluptatem}, {userId: 6, id: 53, title: est vel sequi voluptatem nemo quam molestiae modi enim}, {userId: 6, id: 54, title: aut non illo amet perferendis},
{userId: 6, id: 55, title: qui culpa itaque omnis in nesciunt architecto error}, {userId: 6, id: 56, title: omnis qui maiores tempora officiis omnis rerum sed repellat}, {userId: 6, id: 57, title:
libero excepturi voluptatem est architecto quae voluptatum officia tempora}, {userId: 6, id: 58, title: nulla illo consequatur aspernatur veritatis aut error delectus et}, {userId: 6, id: 59,
title: eligendi similique provident nihil}, {userId: 6, id: 60, title: omnis mollitia sunt aliquid eum consequatur fugit minus laudantium}, {userId: 7, id: 61, title: delectus iusto et}, {userId:
7, id: 62, title: eos ea non recusandae iste ut quasi}, {userId: 7, id: 63, title: velit est quam}, {userId: 7, id: 64, title: autem voluptatem amet iure quae}, {userId: 7, id: 65, title:
voluptates delectus iure iste qui}, {userId: 7, id: 66, title: velit sed quia dolor dolores delectus}, {userId: 7, id: 67, title: ad voluptas nostrum et nihil}, {userId: 7, id: 68, title: qui
quasi nihil aut voluptatum sit dolore minima}, {userId: 7, id: 69, title: qui aut est}, {userId: 7, id: 70, title: et deleniti unde}, {userId: 8, id: 71, title: et vel corporis}, {userId: 8, id:
72, title: unde exercitationem ut}, {userId: 8, id: 73, title: quos omnis officia}, {userId: 8, id: 74, title: quia est eius vitae dolor}, {userId: 8, id: 75, title: aut quia expedita non},
{userId: 8, id: 76, title: dolorem magnam facere itaque ut reprehenderit tenetur corrupti}, {userId: 8, id: 77, title: cupiditate sapiente maiores iusto ducimus cum excepturi veritatis quia},
{userId: 8, id: 78, title: est minima eius possimus ea ratione velit et}, {userId: 8, id: 79, title: ipsa quae voluptas natus ut suscipit soluta quia quidem}, {userId: 8, id: 80, title: id nihil
reprehenderit}, {userId: 9, id: 81, title: quibusdam sapiente et}, {userId: 9, id: 82, title: recusandae consequatur vel amet unde}, {userId: 9, id: 83, title: aperiam odio fugiat}, {userId: 9,
id: 84, title: est et at eos expedita}, {userId: 9, id: 85, title: qui voluptatem consequatur aut ab quis temporibus praesentium}, {userId: 9, id: 86, title: eligendi mollitia alias aspernatur vel
ut iusto}, {userId: 9, id: 87, title: aut aut architecto}, {userId: 9, id: 88, title: quas perspiciatis optio}, {userId: 9, id: 89, title: sit optio id voluptatem est eum et}, {userId: 9, id: 90,
title: est vel dignissimos}, {userId: 10, id: 91, title: repellendus praesentium debitis officiis}, {userId: 10, id: 92, title: incidunt et et eligendi assumenda soluta quia recusandae}, {userId:
10, id: 93, title: nisi qui dolores perspiciatis}, {userId: 10, id: 94, title: quisquam a dolores et earum vitae}, {userId: 10, id: 95, title: consectetur vel rerum qui aperiam modi eos aspernatur
ipsa}, {userId: 10, id: 96, title: unde et ut molestiae est molestias voluptatem sint}, {userId: 10, id: 97, title: est quod aut}, {userId: 10, id: 98, title: omnis quia possimus nesciunt deleniti
assumenda sed autem}, {userId: 10, id: 99, title: consectetur ut id impedit dolores sit ad ex aut}, {userId: 10, id: 100, title: enim repellat iste}]
quidem molestiae enim
```

But the `list.length()` is being rendered as 0 in the `Text()` widget.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use null safety .

Comment: Its already null-safe.

Comment: Can you share  api_model.dart

Comment: I am not using that. Thats irrelevant.

Comment: https://medium.com/@rajajawahar77/create-your-first-api-call-in-flutter-a04d023ebd50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't updating the UI when the data is fetched.
What's happening is, the Text() widget is displaying the initial value of photoAlbums which is []. After you fetch the data, set state to see the changes. You could try it like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
fetchData();
super.initState();
}

fetchData(){
  postRequest().then((albums) {
 setState((){
photoAlbums = albums;
 });
print('PHOTOALBUMS ===> $photoAlbums');
print(photoAlbums[0]['title']);
});
}
```